# Parallel and wget to download and generate ordered numeral filenames

Tags: command-line, bash, wget

I have a `filelist` with thousands of absolute paths to inconsistently named files, like this:

```
file1A-2
file-76B
fileC-23
  (...)
file9B-1
```

I'm looking for a way to use `parallel`, `wget`/`curl`/`aria2` or similar tools to download all files from the `filelist` using multiple connections and processes, while saving each file with a new name in a correct order, like this:

```
file1A-2     >    file0001
file-76B     >    file0002
fileC-23     >    file0003
           (...)
file9B-1     >    file9999
```

Comment: Also, why doesn't this work `cat filelist.txt | parallel --gnu "wget -O $(date +%s%N) {}"` ? It generates only timestamp once.

Comment: You can read the file without the comments using this command `cat filelist | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)`

Comment: Oh, thank you. I still need to figure out how to dynamically name the files for `wget -O filename` so I can use `parallel` with it

Comment: Why do you need `parallel` here?

Comment: To download multiple files simultaneously, not one after one.

Comment: You don't need `parallel` for that. Just send `wget` to the background using `wget .... &` in Thomas W.'s answer, and then use a `wait` after the `for` loop to wait for all those `wget`s to finish.

Comment: Isn't `parallel` more efficient and simpler?
I'm using:

`parallel --no-notice -a filelist.txt -j16 wget -q {} -O '{=$_=sprintf("file%05d.ts", $job->seq())=}'` and it generates files named like `file00001.ts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic idea:

```
i=0
for url in $(grep -v '#' "$1") ; do 
  ((i++))
  wget --output-document="file"$(printf "%03d" $i) "$url"
done
```

I have no experience with `parallel`, but this seems to do the job:

```
i=0
for s in $(grep -v '#' "$1") ; do 
  ((i++))
  parallel --no-notice -n0 wget --output-document="file"$(printf "%03d" $i) "$s" ::: {1..1}
done
```

These scripts expect the list file as an argument on the command line.

Comment: I think you meant `cat filelist | grep -v '#'` inside `$()`

Comment: That works, too.  You needn't necessarily *pipe* text into grep, you can also give it (a) file name(s).

Comment: This works, but it's missing the parallel there, which I need :(